# Hadoop Hive Database

Tags: php, hadoop, hive, thrift

I'm new to Hadoop Hive, now i'm connecting Hive PHP using Apache thrift, its working good. I want to know where is the Hive Database file store in server ? (Database file path). Can anybody please help me, i want to transfer my tables to another server.

Comment: Have you checked /usr/hive/warehouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is stored on HDFS, not on the local file system.

Try running this from your job-tracker:

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/
```

That's the default path at least.